# Is there an open source, gratis SFTP client with the option to be automatically upgraded?

Tags: open-source, ftp, ssh, portable, sftp

I often prefer to log in to my server environments by SFTP rather than SSH due to me feeling more comfortable using SFTP (GUI) programs over SSH (CLUI) programs for some particular tasks.

For example, I often prefer to change a file with Visual Studio Code rather than with Nano;
I carefully assume it might me a bad habit due to increase in complexity.

So far I used WinSCP and FileZilla but as far I recall their communities don't allow automatic upgrades.

- I personally use Windows 10 but would generally prefer an operating system independent program;
- I personally use Visual Studio Code (VSCODE) as main GUI plain text editor but I would generally prefer an editor independent program

Is there (such) an open source, gratis, SFTP client with the option to be automatically upgraded,
<sub>which its community doesn't have plan to cancel this ability,</sub>

**?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**WinSCP** allows [automatic updates to donors](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/updates#automatic_upgrade). So it's not "gratis". But it is possible and only $9 donation (or equivalent) is required.

---

**FileZilla** allows automatic updates to anyone (on Windows). See [How to automatically update FileZilla?](https://superuser.com/q/833857/213663#833923)

Answer (score 0):

**[Cyberduck](https://cyberduck.io/download/)** has automatic updates (using Sparkle).